# Operating on undefined variable - null coalescing

Tags: javascript, undefined, null-coalescing

```
function add(num) { 
  var sum;
  for (var i = 1; i < num + 1; i++){
    sum = (sum || 0) + i;
  }; 
  return sum;     
}
add(9);
```

What is a keyword to describe the behavior for defining sum when it gets added to "i" in the for loop? Is this a ternary operation? Obviously the first time it loops through it is undefined, so javascript chooses 0. Why is that?

Comment: It's the logical `or` operator. The pattern is a variant of "null coalescing".

Comment: make sure to use for(var i = ...) instead of for(i = ...), otherwise you create a global variable.

Comment: It would be much better to initialize `var sum = 0` and avoid the awkward expression within the loop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "or" operator `||` works like this:

- If the first operand is "truthy," the first operand is returned.

  Otherwise, the second operand is returned.

Since `undefined` is *not* [**truthy**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy), `sum || 0` is zero the first time through the loop.

<strike>I don't know that there's a specific term for this behavior.</strike> *  It's simply a convenient way to initialize a variable which may not have been pre-initialized.  In your example, it would make more sense to initialize the variable at the start:

```
function add(num) { 
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 1; i < num + 1; i++){
    sum += i;
  }; 
  return sum;     
}
```

---

Note that this has nothing to do with the [**conditional (ternary) operator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
condition ? expr1 : expr2
```

---

* With credit to @joews, there *is* a term for this behavior:  "null coalescing"

But note his caveat:

> It's a common logic bug to use this pattern where the first operand
>   could legitimately be falsy. Never use `var a = b || c` where, say, `0` is
>   a valid value for `b`.

Comment: It's a common logic bug to use this pattern where the first operand could legitimately be falsy. Never use `var a = b || c` where, say, `0` is a valid value for `b`.

Comment: @joews: also need to look-out where `"0"` is NOT a legitimate value (form values)...